# Swift ViewController does not respond to -getFile, Could not connect action, target class

Tags: swift, cocoa, viewcontroller

[My code](https://github.com/arslan2012/Lazy-Hackintosh-Image-Generator) works all fine but there is always two console message every time I run it.
app works fine but the messages just bugs me so much. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and what does these console message means,thanks

```
2016-06-13 14:31:15.014 
LazyHackintoshGenerator[1625:37250] Could not connect action, target class 
LazyHackintoshGenerator.ViewController does not respond to -getFile:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a control's action in your storyboard is linked to a method getfile that no longer exists

Answer (score 3):

1. Select your ViewController.
2. Right-click on its “View Controller” icon (the blue circle with a white square inside).
3. Look for warning icons (yellow triangles).
4. Hover over them. An explanation of the problem will appear.
   As Feldur said, the problem is probably a leftover link from your storyboard to a method that does not exist anymore (maybe you renamed it or deleted it manually). Remove the link by clicking on the cross, and, if needed, re-link to the appropriate method in your code.

---

*Here is an example of what it will look like in Interface Builder.*

[image: Interface Builder screenshot]